# Matrix $P$ with conjugate columns and real vector $x \implies P^{-1} x$ has conjugate entries

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[Background]

I came accross this problem while studying real matrices with complex Eigenvalues. If $A$ is a real matrix, the nonreal Eigenvalues occur in conjugate pairs, and so do the corresponding Eigenvectors. We can construct a transformation matrix $P$ with the Eigenvectors as columns such that $A=PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal. Now, the book used by our university (Toegepaste Algebra, oefeningen en extra's - V. Rijmen, H. Van Hamme) introduces a complex vector $w$ such that $Pw$ is real and claims that the entries in $w$ corresponding to conjugate columns are conjugate. As we can construct an $A$ to fit any $P$, I deduced the following must hold:

Suppose that $P$ is a complex, non-singular $n\times n$-matrix of which the
nonreal columns occur in conjugate pairs and that $x$ is a real
vector. 
 Then if $P$ has conjugate columns i and j, the i'th and
j'th entries of $P^{-1}x$ are conjugate.

How could one prove this?

e.g.

$$
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 2+i & 2-i \\
0 & i & -i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1+2i & -1-2i \\
2 & 1+i & 1-i & 0 & 0 \\
3 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
x =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
5 \\
0 \\
0 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then
$$
P^{-1}x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
-3/2-5/2i \\
-3/2+5/2i \\
1-1/2i \\
1+1/2i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As you can see, the 2nd and 3rd and the 4th and 5th columns of $P$ are conjugate, and so are the 2nd and 3rd and the 4th and 5th entries of $P^{-1}x$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question overnight, and I will leave the answer here for future reference.

As $P$ has conjugate columns, there is a permutation matrix $Q$ that switches the conjugate pairs. I.e. $$\overline{P} = P\cdot Q$$
In my example with
$$
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 2+i & 2-i \\
0 & i & -i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1+2i & -1-2i \\
2 & 1+i & 1-i & 0 & 0 \\
3 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$Q$ would be
$$
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Switching the 2nd and 3rd column and the 4th and 5th column of $P$. Note, in particular, that $Q^T=Q$.

Now suppose $x$ is a real vector and call $w=P^{-1}x$. Then $Pw=x$ is real, so
$$Pw = \overline{Pw} = \overline{P}\overline{w} = PQ\overline{w}$$
P is invertible (question statement), so this implies
$$w = Q\overline{w}$$

I.e. if the $i$'th and $j$'th column of $P$ are conjugate, then so are the $i$'th and $j$'th entry of $w$.